# Android fullBackupContent and Realm

Tags: android, realm, android-backup-service

I want to use Android fullBackupContent to backup my Realm files. 
I use those files to save the state of the user and keep the sections that he unlocked open, so if the user will re-install the app or update it those sections will still be unlocked.

Is it possible to use Android fullBackupContent to save Realm files? 
Is there a better/easier way to do it?

Just to be clear, I'm talking about this fullBackupContent:
 http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2015/07/auto-backup-for-apps-made-simple.html

Comment: We should document this, but we haven't :( See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2603 The key point is the Realm should not be changed during backup or restoring. So maybe you can consider to use `Realm.writeCopyTo()` to create a copy of Realm file and backup it. To restore it, you can use `Realm.deleteRealm()` to try to delete the Realm file first, then copy the backup file back.